# Setup couchbase in ec2 across multiple availability zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, couchbase

I am trying to setup couchbase cluster on AWS. I want my nodes to be distributed across multiple availability zones. 
Ec2 instances with in an availability zone are able to access each other using the ip (Private DNS) which is assigned to them during creation and which does not change even if we restart the machine.

I am not able to access an Ec2 instance from other AZ using this (Private DNS). One way this can be done is by using Elastic Ip which has a limit per region.

Question here is **How to access one Ec2 instance from other EC2 instance in another AZ without elastic ip?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to use Elastic IP for this. Your statement that Elastic IP is a solution to your issue is not correct. You want to use the **Private IP** assigned to the instance when you created it.

The private IP will not change as long as the instances are deployed inside a VPC.

You have to use the private IP in order to keep all network traffic inside the VPC. Then you just need to make sure your Security Groups are configured correctly to allow traffic between the instances.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Web Services Operates Split-horizon DNS (AKA Split-Brain DNS).  The best practice when deploying couchbase onto EC2 is to use hostnames not IP addresses, see http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/install/cloud-deployment.html .  Amazon will automatically give a different IP when resolving the hostname depending if the source of the request is internal or external.